# How do I send Intent Result Data to 2 Activity behind (skipping previous activity)?

Tags: android, android-intent

I create an app that has custom suggestions feature. `MainActivity` will show list of items and also has a `SearchView` to search something from the list. When the user put something on a `SearchView`, the list of suggestions will be shown. When I click one of the suggestions, it will send the intent data that is in the suggestion to a searchable activity (`SearchActivity`). In this activity, it will check if the Intent come from `ACTION_SEARCH` or `ACTION_VIEW`. If `ACTION_SEARCH`, it will show the query in this activity. Otherwise, it will send Intent to open `DetailsActivity`. In `DetailsActivity`, user can delete this item. When user click delete button, `DetailsACtivity` will send intent result to `MainActivity`, skipping `SearchActivity` (I use finish when `SearchActivity` send intent to open `DetailsActivity`). My code show no error, but my item is not deleted, why the intent result is not working?

Below is my code snippet

**MainActivity.java**

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch(requestCode) {
            case 12345:
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    int pos = data.getIntExtra("DELETE", -1);
                    itemList.remove(pos);
                    mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(pos);
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    }
```

**SearchActivity.java**

```
    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            txtQuery.setText("Search Query: " + query);
        } else if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent detail = new Intent(this, DetailsActivity.class);

            int pos = intent.getIntExtra(SearchManager.EXTRA_DATA_KEY);
            intent.putExtra("POS", pos);
            startActivityForResult(detail, 12345);
            finish();
        }
    }
```

**DetailsActivity.java**

```
        removeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int pos = getIntent().getIntExtra("POS", -1);
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("DELETE", pos);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
```

Comment: instead of `setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);` use  `setResult(12345, intent);` for receiving the result.

Comment: remove the `finish()` method in else loop, If you are finishing the activity how you will receive the result...

Comment: It still doesn't work. without `finish()`, DetailsActivity will go back to SearchActivity if I click back button instead of skipping it and go to MainActivity.

Comment: Mr stackex result will be delivered to the activity from where you called...You are calling `startActivityForResult()` from `SearchActivity` and you are trying to get the result from MainActivity..

Comment: ah, that's right. Do you have any idea how to send item identifier to MainActivity so that I can delete it from MainActivity? Note: If I click the item from itemList in MainActivity, it will go to detailsActivity, and If I click removeButton, the item will be deleted gracefully. The problem I go to DetailsActivity from search suggestions through SearchActivity.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use result forwarding.

`MainActivity` launches `SearchActivity` using `startActivityForResult()`

`SearchActivity` should launch `DetailsActivity` like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailsActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

This tells the framework that the results from `DetailsActivity` shouldbe returned to `MainActivity`.

**NOTE** that you launch `DetailsActivity` using `startActivity()` and **not** using `startActivityForResult()`;

Comment: Thanks, it gives me insight, but how do I launch SearchActivity using `startActivityForResult()` since I launch it from MainActivity using searchview?